# OpenLayers 3 right click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I am trying to listen to right mouse click , i tried `"rightclick"` as in documentation says , but it doesn't work.

Can any one say why it doesn't work ???

```
 map.on('rightclick', function (evt) {
            var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
                if (typeof (feature.getId()) != "undefined") {
                    return feature;
                }
            });

            if (feature) {
                var registeredObjectId = -1;

                if (typeof MapObjects !== "undefined") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < MapObjects.ObjectResult.length; i++) {
                        if (feature.p.name === MapObjects.ObjectResult[i].Id) {
                            registeredObjectId = i;
                        }
                    }
                }

                var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
                var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

                if (registeredObjectId === -1) {
                    popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                    $(element).popover({
                        'placement': 'top',
                        'html': true,
                        'content': "<a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='DeleteCoordinate(\"" + feature.getId() + "\")'>Delete</a>"
                    });
                    $(element).popover('show');
                    $(element2).popover('destroy');
                }
                else {
                    popup2.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                    console.log(MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Name);
                    console.log(MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Value);
                    $(element2).popover({
                        'placement': 'top',
                        'html': true,
                        'content': "<label>" + MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Name + "</label></br><label>" + MapObjects.ObjectResult[registeredObjectId].Value + "</label></br><a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='DeleteCoordinate(\"" + feature.getId() + "\")'>Delete</a>"
                    });
                    $(element2).popover('show');
                    $(element).popover('destroy');
                }

            } else {
                $(element).popover('destroy');
                $(element2).popover('destroy');
            }
        });
```

On "click" it works, "pointerup" works as right click ,but includes also left .

Comment: Have you tried to search for it? I have found so many different and highly upvoted solutions to your question in seconds... If you ask because none of these work, you should state it in your question.

Comment: Well i mentioned that "rightclick" doesnt work , "contextmenu" also

Comment: Does it work for you in other demos? (To outrule your browser as the culprit)

Comment: Answer ... http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/148450/50718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event should't be `rightclick`, but `mousedown`. Information about mousebuttons is in its eventArgs. Try `evt.button`, which has values 1, 2 or 3 for left, middle or right mouse buttons in that order for all modern browsers or `evt.button == 2` for older IE.